# Verify the correctness of a sentence, preferably with a custom corpus

Tags: nlp

**The Goal**

My goal is to create an API that can verify how grammatically correct a sentence is.  I am using a Markov Chain to generate a bunch of lines and I want to rank them by how much sense they make.

**I want to be able to have some input like:**

```
[ 
  "This sentence is totally great!",
  "Not great so sentence this one.",
  "From on in where is are for pig."
]
```

and then get some output like:

```
[
    0.71,
    0.30,
    -0.43,
]
```

**Where I'm currently at**

I've looked at using the Stanford Parser but I don't think there's a way to use your own corpus.

Currently, I am using a Microsoft joint probability cognitive service, which also doesn't allow a custom corpus and seems pretty rudimentary.

**Direct questions**

Is this a solved problem?

What is this kind of problem/research called? (So I know how to google around for it)

What methods are there for accomplishing something like this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are unable to use your own corpus with stanford parser, but you can always use [OpenNLP](https://opennlp.apache.org/documentation/1.6.0/manual/opennlp.html).

Here's what I would do:

1. create a corpus of parsed sentences, with some correct sentences. I can stop here and do what you're doing. Or else I'll do 2.
2. create a [word2vec](https://deeplearning4j.org/word2vec) model and see how close(cosine similarity) is the parsed input sentence. Hopefully, you'll get good results.

you can have a quick start [here](http://self-learning-java-tutorial.blogspot.in/2015/10/opennlp-sentence-detector-training.html) for using OpenNLP.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve your need is to create a language model from your corpus and then evaluate your test sentences against it which will give you some sort of score. You can look at the results and see if you need a more sophisticated approach.

I would start with a character language model, probably up to 6-grams for 10k sentences or so, longer if you have lots of data, shorter with less. You will have to play with it. You can also try token language models in the 2-4 token range. Tutorial for LingPipe is [here](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/lm/read-me.html) .
Not exactly your use case but it least it is concrete.

It is easy to build and sensitive to your corpus.

You could try and treat the problem as a spell check problem where instead of spelling correction you are doing grammar correction with the backing language model informing whether the edits have improved things. The more edits required to get a good estimate will translate to a lower score for the original's grammaticality. The closest code to that is our tutorial [here](http://alias-i.com/lingpipe/demos/tutorial/querySpellChecker/read-me.html).

But it will need a lot of modification to apply to the grammar use case.

There are many ways to approach your problem if the language model approach doesn't work but I would start there.

Breck